# Does tensorflow.data.experimental.CsvDataset read from the file over and over?

Tags: tensorflow-datasets

I am struggling with long training times with tf.data.Dataset, and am beginning to wonder if reading the CSV file may be a bottleneck. Does [tensorflow.data.experimental.CsvDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/CsvDataset) read from the file over and over?

I consider trying to first import the whole dataset and put it in a numpy array, and then create a new [TF Dataset from tensors](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensors). But such a change will take time, and I don't want to waste time if SO could have told me beforehand that it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly why I got so long training times with CsvDataset, but modifying my code to first import the data to a numpy array and then import it using `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` made the training about **10-100 times faster**. One more, prehaps relevant, change that followed by this, was that the dataset was no longer nested throughout the handling. In the old version, each batch was a tuple of column tensors, whereas in the new version, each batch is simply a tensor. (Further speedups may be achieved by removing transforms tailored to the nested structure, which are now applied to one tensor only.)